# bash, zsh : declare [*] (oh my)

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm working with a bash script that has the following syntax

```
$ declare -a THIS[*]
```

This seems to be illegal in zsh (I get a "no matches found: THIS[*]" error). Can anyone help me translate this to zsh?

Also - what does the `[*]` syntax mean? (I know we're declaring an array, but why the [*]?)

*update*

To provide an example of where the code is used, and explain how it is valid - I've copied a few lines from Eric Engstrom's post on [password free ssh](http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-agent.php)

```
declare -a SSSHA_KEYS[*]

# --- PARSE ARGS --- #
sssha_parse_args() {
  local OPTIND=1
  while getopts "xe:k:t:" OPT; do
    #echo "$OPT $OPTARG $OPTIND"
    case $OPT in
      t) SSSHA_ARGS="-t $OPTARG" ;;
      e) SSSHA_ENV="$OPTARG" ;;
      k) [ -f "${OPTARG}" ] && SSSHA_KEYS[${#SSSHA_KEYS[*]}]="$OPTARG" ;;
      x) SSSHA_STOP_ON_EXIT=$OPT
    esac
  done
  shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

  # set default key, if none specified
  if [ -z "${SSSHA_KEYS[*]}" ]; then
    for key in $HOME/.ssh/id_[rd]sa; do
      [ -f "$key" ] && SSSHA_KEYS[${#SSSHA_KEYS[*]}]="$key"
    done
  fi
}
```

I believe the `[*]` is being used as some kind of dynamic iterator (as we don't know how many items it will have later). I'd just like to know of the equivalent declaration in zsh!

Comment: What do you mean by "(oh my)"?!

Comment: There is exactly no way to control how much space can array occupy in zsh (unless you are willing to make it read-only), so just try to do `declare -a SSSHA_KEYS`. Trusting the explanation of @ormaaj these declarations should be equal. Other posted code is likely to work without modifications, except for `SSSHA_KEYS[${#SSSHA_KEYS[*]}]=smth`: it is going to add a key, am I right? Use `SSHA_KEYS+=( smth )` as in zsh array indexes start from 1 and `ARR[ARR_LENGTH]` will assign to last item, not after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Bash has `declare`. The kshes and zsh have `typeset`. That code is nonsensical in all of them, and since shells disagree about the parsing of the arguments to *declaration commands* like `declare` and `typeset` (with Bash in particular, `-a` alters parsing in a specific way), it's going to do a different unpredictable, potentially dangerous thing in each.

Specifically how Bash is interpreting this - from the manpage:

> declare -a name[subscript] is also accepted; the subscript is ignored.

So since it's unquoted - if there's a file in the current directory named `THIS*` then Bash would throw an illegal name error due to the pathname expansion. Otherwise it will just create an empty array named "THIS".

What `[*]` means depends upon context. Unquoted in an ordinary command evaluation context, it's a character class matching only literal asterisks. If used in a parameter expansion following an array name, it expands all elements of the array to a single word separated by the first character of IFS.

`declare` in bash declares variables, returns their values, sets attributes, and affects function scope. See: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare

**edit**: Given the example that's now in the question, in bash the behavior is as described above. The `[*]` should be deleted from the `declare`. That code has a number of other issues such as attempting to put arguments into strings, using all-caps variable names, and using `[` instead of `[[` in a script that's clearly not intended to run on a minimal POSIX sh.

Comment: Zsh does have `declare`, but it is an alias to typeset. Note: if you do `emulate bash`, then `declare -a THIS[*]`, then the message will change: `declare: THIS[*]: can't create local array elements` if `THIS` is not defined and `declare: THIS[*]: array elements must be scalar` if `THIS` is defined with `declare -a THIS`. I do not know what `declare -a THIS[*]` is supposed to do and in which context it is called, thus I can say nothing more.

Comment: * `emulate bash` is the same as `emulate sh`.

Comment: @ZyX Ah yes, I should have guessed it had `declare` as part of its compatibility features. I can think of a few Bash-only corner cases where `THIS[*]` by itself might come up, but they definitely aren't things most people would know or care about, and definitely aren't relevant here (e.g. an argument to `unset`, most others involve indirect expansion).

Comment: @ormaaj - cases where `THIS[*]` come up are relevant here, as I'm asking what it means.

Comment: @danodonovan Without more context it's impossible to say what whoever wrote it was thinking. They probably have no idea how arrays work. I thought I already answered it. If there happens to be a file named THIS* in the current directory, you get an illegal name error, otherwise in Bash, declaring an empty array while specifying an index just creates the array and ignores the specified index, which in the case of * and a non-associative indexed array is invalid. Regardless, it isn't something anybody would ever want.