# Strange behaviour of declare/typeset with "options" array in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I attempted to declare a variable named `options` in a script for zsh. Turned out that it's some reserved name and zsh stores an associative array under it.

```
function mcve() {
    options='';
}

$ mcve
mcve:1: options: attempt to set slice of associative array
```

Tried to look at its contents with `declare` and encountered a strange behaviour. The output is different before and after first occurence of the above error.

```
$ zsh
$ declare options
options

$ zsh
$ mcve
mcve:1: options: attempt to set slice of associative array
$ declare options
options=(autolist on printexitvalue off...<20 more lines>)
```

**What's happening? Why is output different? Is the `options` array declared at the moment of first attempt to use it?**

I've heard that [`typeset` should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195261/2790048) instead of `declare`, but my `man zshbuiltins` says they're perfectly equal.

Also, this runs without failure:

```
function mcve() {
declare options;
options='';
echo ok;
}

$ zsh
$ mcve
ok
```

Why is this different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `options` associative array is documented in `man zshmodules`, under `ZSH/PARAMETERS`. I can't explain the behavior of `declare options`, but I will note that `print $options[@]` will output a list of on/off values even when `declare options` shows nothing.

In your last example, `declare options` inside a function definition always declares a new local variable, whether or not a global by the same name already exists.

Comment: Thank you, that, indeed, explains a lot. What's the `$variable[@]` syntax called or where can I read about it?

Comment: That is the syntax for expanding all element of an array. Arrays are described in details in `man zshparam`.